# Google Maps Marker Click Event

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'd like to populate a google map with several markers. When the user clicks on a marker I would like it to send the user to a different webpage which is designated for that location. (for example: lets say the markers represent homes, when you click on a marker it takes you to a page with more information about the home)

What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You will need to attach an event listener to each marker. The click handler can set `document.location` to the URL of the page you want to go to.

```
var marker = new GMarker(location);
GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    window.location = theURL;
});
map.addOverlay(marker);
```

Since you will probably be adding markers in a loop, you will need to make sure each one gets its own URL. Since closures keep the actual variables they access (not their values), you probably need to put at least `addListener` code in its own function to create its own scope. Your loop would look kind of like this:

```
function createMarker(location, url) {
    var marker = new GMarker(location);
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        window.location = url;
    });
    return marker;
}

// Assuming locations is an array of objects with lat, lng, and url properties
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var loc = locations[i];
    map.addOverlay(createMarker(new GLatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng), loc.url));
}
```

Comment: Readers of this answer should note that GEvent needs to be replaced with google.maps.event if you are using v3 of the API. Have a look at the other answer with high votes!

Answer (score 51):

I believe that as of google map v3, GEvent is not recognized, the below worked for me

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    window.location = url;
});
```

Comment: this worked perfectly for me as well in v3. Don't know about those GEvents and such, chose this example first :)

Comment: Yeah, I think @Mike should change accepted answer, as previous one was valid in 2010

Comment: This example doesn't work in a loop due to the scope issues mentioned in the other answer.